# Замыкание. Разъяснение простого момента

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Задание: Создайте функцию `filter(arr, func)`, которая получает массив `arr` и возвращает новый, в который входят только те элементы `arr`, для которых `func` возвращает `true`.

Ниже представлено правильное решение, мой вариант был идентичен, кроме проверки  `if (arr[i] == true)`, разумеется ничего не выходило.

У меня не получается осознать почему именно `func(kkk)` ? Я вроде понимаю что `func(kkk) = !!arr[i]` (da?). Как так выходит то?

```
function filter(arr, func) {
      var newArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; arr.length > i; i++) {
          var kkk = arr[i]
          if (func(kkk)) {
            newArray.push(kkk);
          }

        }
         return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: *мой вариант был идентичен, кроме проверки  `if (arr[i] == true)`, разумеется ничего не выходило.* Вам надо было проверять не то, что элемент массива есть `TRUE`, а то, что функция для аргумента, равного этому элементу, вернёт `TRUE`. Так что ни разу не "идентичен".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я вроде понимаю что func(kkk) = !!arr[i] (da?)

Нет.

В Вашем коде нет никаких замыканий. Функция `func`, подаваемая в `filter`, проверяет для данного элемента массива условие фильтрации, про которое процедура фильтрации ничего не знает. Точно также процедура фильтрации (Ваш код в вопросе) ничего не знает о том, что храниться в массиве. Все эти знания содержатся внутри колбэка `func`.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагается что есть ещё какая то функция которая называется `func` (это просто имя такое, может вас это сбило с толку). Она принимает элемент массива и возвращает `true` или `false`.

Comment: Вот, понимаю что она принимает элемент массива и что она возвращает true, но почему она это делает, тела функции же нет.
Как она производит проверку на `true`
Типа, она ведь даже нигде не объявлена как функция